# Two pairs two pairs win 

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, poker-strategy, poker-tools, pokertracker

On the board is ( 2,2,5,3,3)

Player one has (Ace, 6)

Player two has (7,5)

Both players have a two pair who wins?

Answer (score 2):

Player 1's hand (best 5-card choice) is 3322A, so two-pair, threes and twos.

Player 2's hand (best 5-card choice) is 55337, so two-pair, fives and threes.

Since fives beat threes, player 2 wins the hand.